# pandas df.loc[z,x]=y how to improve speed?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, time-series

I have identified one pandas command

```
timeseries.loc[z, x] = y
```

to be responsible for most of the time spent in an iteration. And now I am looking for better approaches to accelerate it. The loop covers not even 50k elements (and production goal is ~250k or more), but already needs a sad 20 seconds.

Here is my code (ignore the top half, it is just the timing helper)

```
def populateTimeseriesTable(df, observable, timeseries):
    """
    Go through all rows of df and 
    put the observable into the timeseries 
    at correct row (symbol), column (tsMean).
    """

    print "len(df.index)=", len(df.index)  # show number of rows

    global bf, t
    bf = time.time()                       # set 'before' to now
    t = dict([(i,0) for i in range(5)])    # fill category timing with zeros

    def T(i):
        """
        timing helper: Add passed time to category 'i'. Then set 'before' to now.
        """
        global bf, t 
        t[i] = t[i] + (time.time()-bf)
        bf = time.time()        

    for i in df.index:             # this is the slow loop
        bf = time.time()

        sym = df["symbol"][i]
        T(0)

        tsMean = df["tsMean"][i]
        T(1)

        tsMean = tsFormatter(tsMean)
        T(2)

        o = df[observable][i]
        T(3)

        timeseries.loc[sym, tsMean] = o
        T(4)

    from pprint import pprint
    print "times needed (total = %.1f seconds) for each command:" % sum(t.values())
    pprint (t)

    return timeseries
```

With (not important, not slow)

```
def tsFormatter(ts):
    "as human readable string, only up to whole seconds"
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(ts))
```

.
.

--> **The to-be-optimized code is in the for-loop.**

(T, and t are just helper function & dict, for the timing.)

I have timed every step. The vast majority of time:

```
len(df.index)= 47160
times needed (total = 20.2 seconds) for each command:
{0: 1.102,
 1: 0.741,
 2: 0.243,
 3: 0.792,
 4: 17.371}
```

is spent **in the last step**

```
timeseries.loc[sym, tsMean] = o
```

I have already downloaded and install *pypy* - but sadly, that doesn't support pandas yet.

Any ideas how to speed up populating a 2D array?

Thanks!

---

Edit: Sorry, hadn't mentioned - 'timeseries' is a dataframe too:

```
timeseries = pd.DataFrame({"name": titles}, index=index)
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of object `timeseries` is.  But, if it has a '.loc` method, it may have a `.at` method.  If you are assigning at a specific location, `.at` should be quicker.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, hadn't mentioned: timeseries is a dataframe:

    timeseries = pd.DataFrame({"name": titles}, index=index)

I have added that to the OP now.

Comment: I will be looking into that .at function. Thanks a lot, @piRSquared

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

=====================================================================

@jezrael has provided an interesting comparison and i decided to repeat it using more indexing methods and against 10M rows DF (actually the size doesn't matter in this particular case):

setup:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**7, 5), columns=list('abcde'))

In [16]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000000 entries, 0 to 9999999
Data columns (total 5 columns):
a    float64
b    float64
c    float64
d    float64
e    float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 381.5 MB

In [17]: df.shape
Out[17]: (10000000, 5)
```

Timing:

```
In [37]: %timeit df.loc[random.randint(0, 10**7), 'b']
1000 loops, best of 3: 502 µs per loop

In [38]: %timeit df.iloc[random.randint(0, 10**7), 1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 394 µs per loop

In [39]: %timeit df.at[random.randint(0, 10**7), 'b']
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.8 µs per loop

In [41]: %timeit df.iat[random.randint(0, 10**7), 1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.9 µs per loop

In [42]: %timeit df.ix[random.randint(0, 10**7), 'b']
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.8 µs per loop

In [43]: %timeit df.ix[random.randint(0, 10**7), 1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 503 µs per loop
```

Results as a bar plot:

[image]

Timing data as DF:

```
In [88]: r
Out[88]:
       method  timing
0         loc   502.0
1        iloc   394.0
2          at    66.8
3         iat    32.9
4    ix_label    64.8
5  ix_integer   503.0

In [89]: r.to_dict()
Out[89]:
{'method': {0: 'loc',
  1: 'iloc',
  2: 'at',
  3: 'iat',
  4: 'ix_label',
  5: 'ix_integer'},
 'timing': {0: 502.0,
  1: 394.0,
  2: 66.799999999999997,
  3: 32.899999999999999,
  4: 64.799999999999997,
  5: 503.0}}
```

Plotting

```
ax = sns.barplot(data=r, x='method', y='timing')
ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
[ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() + 0.2, p.get_height() + 5)) for p in ax.patches]
ax.set_xlabel('indexing method', size=20)
ax.set_ylabel('timing (microseconds)', size=20)
```

Comment: wow wow wow. Thank you so much. This is truly enlightening. So my scepticism about such slowness was justified indeed. I had chosen perhaps the most comfortable solution, using .loc - but I bought it with a 7.5 to 15.3 fold punishment in time complexity, compared to .at and .iat - thanks a lot, this is very valuable information!

Comment: Done. Thx! Much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot accept BOTH answers. Hmmmm ... yours has this really easy to read histogram output. But @jezrael was first to answer, and his answer is very good too. What to do now?

Answer (score 7):

I always think [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is the fastest, but not. [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) is faster:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.at[2, 'B'])
6
print (df.ix[2, 'B'])
6
print (df.loc[2, 'B'])
6

In [77]: %timeit df.at[2, 'B']
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.6 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit df.ix[2, 'B']
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.7 µs per loop

In [79]: %timeit df.loc[2, 'B']
1000 loops, best of 3: 681 µs per loop
```

EDIT:

I try [`MaxU`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761363/2901002) `df` and differences are caused `random.randint` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**7, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))


In [4]: %timeit (df.ix[2, 'B'])
The slowest run took 25.80 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit (df.ix[random.randint(0, 10**7), 'B'])
The slowest run took 9.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 28 µs per loop
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you very much! Now I am wondering how to explain away the differences between your results, jezrael, and those which @MaxU has reported there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37761363/6185262

Comment: is it perhaps his df is 10M rows, and yours is small? So perhaps .ix is the fastest for small dataframes, and .at / .iat the fastest for huge ones?

Comment: I think timings are best for comparing of methods and in each PC are little different. And these timings not depens on length of dataframe. and `iat` is the fastest, but you need position of column - if dont know position and only column name, you cannot use iat - using ix is the fastest approach.

Comment: The best is explain it in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

Comment: And if use [`anaconda`](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) - you can try check timings in your pc too.

Comment: One idea - it is difference between my and maxu results because I use position as int (2) and maxu generate random int - so of course generating of number is some time and select is another time - together is time a bit higher as me (I dont generate random position.)

Comment: I edit solution and add timings with generating `int` and not.

Comment: ahhh, yes. That can explain, indeed. Thank you very much, jezrael. I hope I can accept both of your solutions as solutions to this question.

Comment: Oh no, I cannot. What a pity.

Comment: Yes, only one can be accepted. And it is up to you. Nice day.

Comment: As both your answers are equally good ... I have thrown a thousand coins: sum([random.random() for _ in range(1000)])/1000 and that resulted in 0.4972785257694664 - so MaxU has won, by random choice :-) Nice day to you to!

Comment: Ok. Maybe next time I will be winner. ;-)

Comment: @AltSheets, i like your approach! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding rows inside a loop consider thses performance issues; for around first 1000 to 2000 records "my_df.loc" performance is better and gradually it is become slower by increasing the number of records in loop.

If you plan to do thins inside a big loop(say 10M‌ records or so) you are better to use a mixture of "iloc" and "append"; fill a temp datframe with iloc untill the size gets around 1000, then append it to the original dataframe, and empy the temp dataframe. this would boost your performance around 10 times