# How do I create a DataFrame containing a column where rows are greater than a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with these columns:

```
ID                    int64
Key                   int64
Reference            object
sKey                float64
sName               float64
fKey                 int64
cName                object
ints                  int32
```

I want to create a new DataFrame containing columns `commonName` and `ints` where `ints` is greater than 10, I am doing:

`df_greater_10 = df[['commonName', df[df.ints >= 1997]]]`

I see the problem lies with the expression `df[df.ints >= 1997]` as I'm returning a DataFrame - how can I just get the column of `ints` with values greater than 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of many available [indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). I would recommend `.ix`, because it seems to be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761363/5741205):

```
df_greater_10 = df.ix[df.ints >= 1997, ['commonName', 'ints']]
```

or if you need only `ints` column

```
df_greater_10 = df.ix[df.ints >= 1997, 'ints']
```

Demo:

```
In [123]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 15, (10, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [124]: df
Out[124]:
    a   b   c
0  13  11  14
1  14  10  13
2   7  11   6
3   7  13  12
4   9   9   6
5   7   7   7
6   5   7   8
7   5  11   5
8   9   7   9
9  11  13   7

In [125]: df_greater_10 = df.ix[df.c > 10, ['a','c']]

In [126]: df_greater_10
Out[126]:
    a   c
0  13  14
1  14  13
3   7  12
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

So use `df.loc[...]` or `df.iloc[...]` instead of deprecated `df.ix[...]`

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting an exception `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 13 to array axis with dimension 19106`

Comment: @NRKirby, sorry, i had a typo in my code, it should be working now

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaxU !!

Comment: @NRKirby, i'm always happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you haven't tried `df[df.ints >= 1997]['ints']` first (Maybe I am missing someting, your dataframe is very big?). Here's a demo of how it would work below

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'ints': [1, 2, 3, 10, 11], 'other': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'z']})

', 'y', 'z']})
   ints other
0     1     a
1     2     b
2     3     c
3    10     y
4    11     z

>>> df[df.ints >= 10]
   ints other
3    10     y
4    11     z
>>> df[df.ints >= 10]['ints']
3    10
4    11
```

You can get same result with `df['ints'][df['ints'] >= 10]` too, which makes it more obvious you're only interested in the `ints` column.

Comment: You're not missing anything, I'm a Python novice. I tried `df_greater_10 = df[['commonName' df[df.ints >= 1997]['ints']]]` But I'm getting `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`