# fillna method is slower for square bracket column selection than loc for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I found significant processing time difference in fillna for different column selection techniques of pandas dataframe.
Time taken for `fillna` of dataframe, whose columns are selected using `loc`

```
df1 = df.copy()
t1 = time.time()
df1.loc[:, col] = df1.loc[:, col].fillna(method="ffill")
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

3.908552885055542
```

Time taken for `fillna` of dataframe, whose columns are selected using square bracket:

```
df1 = df.copy()
t1 = time.time()
df1[col] = df1[col].fillna(method="ffill")
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)

223.85472440719604
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte) suggests column selection using loc and square bracket is similar:-
*Selecting a list of columns (df[['A', 'B', 'C']] is the same as df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C']] -> selects columns A, B and C)*

Can anyone please help why there is time difference? Thanks!!

Comment: I tested it and the results are similar; there probably is something off in your tests. Maybe if you provide sample data for this observation, so we can reproduce this massive difference

Comment: Did it with `%%timeit` on my own data, and the `.loc[col]` was 680us while the `[col]` was 396us.

Comment: I uploaded sample dataframe [file](https://github.com/Piyushbalwani/fillna_data/blob/main/sample.pickle). `[col]` 10sec while `loc[col]` 0.3sec for this sample data

Comment: Dataframe indexing a complicated task, involving index and column arrays.  It's much more involved than `numpy` indexing with uses positions and compact multidimensional array.  For a start you could look at `df.__getitiem__` to see the code (probably python) that starts the indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I have collected few point in 2014, while i was testing it over 2M rows. I found it interesting from SO thread which i collected as follows.

In general, you should use loc for label-based assignment, and iloc for integer/positional based assignment, as the spec guarantees that they always operate on the original.

Better to look at [select a subset of a DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

```
- loc is faster, because it does not try to create a copy of the data.

- loc is meant to modify your existing dataframe inplace, which is more memory efficient.

- loc is predictable, it has one behavior.

- df.loc's syntax is explicit, with df.loc[indexer] you know automatically that df.loc is selecting rows. In contrast, it is not clear if df[indexer] will select rows or columns (or raise ValueError) without knowing details about indexer and df.
```

### When using `loc`

`df.loc[:]` = **Dataframe**

`df.loc[int]` = **Dataframe** if you have more than one column and **Series** if you have only 1 column in the dataframe

`df.loc[:, ["col_name"]]` = **Dataframe** if you have more than one row and **Series** if you have only 1 row in the selection

`df.loc[:, "col_name"]` = **Series**

### Not using `loc`

`df["col_name"]` = **Series**

`df[["col_name"]]` = **Dataframe**

look at [here for some interesting details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757844/pandas-df-locz-x-y-how-to-improve-speed/37761363#37761363)Performance Consideration on multiple columns "Chained Assignment" with and without using .loc

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question

Comment: sammywemmy, this is more of a performance related question where a direct answer may not be possible but some hints and used cases can be provided, i have seen discussion over this and saw many champs having their  own opinion based on their use cases,  this is what placed under my answers section because i can not put these learning over comments, hope you get it!