# performance using loc vs simply using inside square brackets

Tags: python, pandas

I know pandas provide various ways to index data, I wanted to know is there a difference between the following two methods from the perspective of performance i.e. which one is faster or both the same?

```py
# method 1

df = table.loc[table.some_col==True, :]

# method 2

df = table[table.some_col==True]
```

Comment: Does the following post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757844/pandas-df-locz-x-y-how-to-improve-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second is a bit faster, for me it has sense, because first solution is combination [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), second only [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
np.random.seed(2021)
table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**7, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
table['some_col'] = table.a > 0.6

In [130]: %timeit table.loc[table.some_col==True, :]
258 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [131]: %timeit df = table[table.some_col==True]
241 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```