# Faster method for complex .loc in large Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, pandas-loc

For each row, I need to get a) the number of and b) the mean score of all rows 28 days prior to that row's `date` with the same `member_ID`.

df:

```
        member_ID     score      date    past28
0              93  0.341937  20090515  20090417
1             496  0.075530  20090515  20090417
2             742  0.072468  20090515  20090417
3             668       NaN  20090515  20090417
4             351  0.581490  20090515  20090417
...           ...       ...       ...       ...
799995        792       NaN  20230225  20230128
799996        180  0.251769  20230225  20230128
799997        413  0.195291  20230225  20230128
799998        786  0.389303  20230225  20230128
799999        235  0.545911  20230225  20230128
```

Rows with NaN score values I want to include in the main loop (ie. get the row's qualifying rows), but I exclude these rows from qualifying_rows for the purpose of calculating valid score_counts and score_averages.

```
score_counts = pd.Series([0] * len(df))
score_averages = pd.Series([None] * len(df))

for id, id_rows in df.groupby('member_ID'):
   for date, date_rows in id_rows.groupby('date'):
      #There can be multiple member_ID on the same date, so I use the first index of date_rows to ensure I exclude current date from past_member_rows
      past_member_rows = id_rows.loc[:date_rows.index[0]-1]
      #For any given row, its past28 value is its date value minus 28 days
      qualifying_rows = past_member_rows.loc[(past_member_rows['date'] >= date_rows['past28'].iloc[0]) & (~past_member_rows['score'].isnull())]
   score_counts[date_rows.index] = len(qualifying_rows)
   score_averages[date_rows.index] = qualifying_rows['score'].mean()
```

With this many .locs it obviously take a very long time and I'd love to hear some recommendations for how to re-think this. I usually employ vectorization but with this relatively complex lookup on a row by row basis I haven't worked out how to do so here.

Comment: What is ```runners```?

Comment: Have fixed. I meant to write date_rows

Comment: Have you looked into combining `groupby` and `rolling`? I think this is where your solution may be

Comment: You probably can use `.at`, which has found to be [significantly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757844/pandas-df-locz-x-y-how-to-improve-speed) than `.loc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact avoid the `id_date` column. Here is a version of your code that is just *slightly* shorter because you can group by two columns and implement `merge` to combine results at the end. You may choose to test the speed with `map` vs. `merge` as well.

As far as I can tell, you need the second dataframe because of the duplicate dates unfortunately. If a way to handle the duplicate dates is found I will update. For now though, my understanding is that to use the time-aware `rolling`, you have to use a date as the index, but you also need unique indices. So, conundrum!

Note that your choice of `left` for `rolling` means the last data point is excluded in the sum and count (and therefore mean). You may change to include it with a different choice for the `closed` parameter.

```
# use datetime type
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# create columns for each member ID & date with a sum and count for that combo
df['sum_date'] = df.groupby(['member_ID', 'date'])['score'].transform('sum')
df['ct_date'] = df.groupby(['member_ID', 'date'])['score'].transform('count')

# sort by date for rolling function
df.sort_values(by=['date', 'member_ID'], inplace=True)

# copy data, drop duplicates, reset index with date
df2 = df.copy().drop_duplicates(['member_ID', 'date'])
df2.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# perform rolling calculations for group
grouped = df2.groupby('member_ID')['sum_date']
rolling_sum = grouped.rolling('28D',closed='left').sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'sum_date':'rolling_sum'})
grouped = df2.groupby('member_ID')['ct_date']
rolling_count = grouped.rolling('28D',closed='left').sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'ct_date':'rolling_ct'})

# merge data, calculate mean, drop extra columns
df = df.merge(rolling_sum, how='left', on = ['member_ID', 'date']).merge(rolling_count, how='left', on=['member_ID', 'date'])
df['rolling_mean'] = df['rolling_sum'] / df['rolling_ct']
df = df.drop(columns=['sum_date', 'ct_date', 'rolling_sum', 'rolling_ct'])
```

Edit to add: In my test I did not include data with `NA`, so you'd want to double check that. If you need to drop them, `groupby` has options for that, or you could move setting `df2` to before `sum_date` and `ct_date`, and drop rows with `NA` values there

Answer (score 0):

With a prompt from 34jbonz and with the help of chatgpt, I managed a 53x speed improvement with the help of `rolling`:

```
df['id_date'] = df['id'].astype('str') + '_' + df['DATE']
df['day_sum'] = df['id_date'].map(df.groupby('id_date')['score'].sum())
df['day_count'] = df['id_date'].map(df.groupby('id_date')['score'].count())
df2 = df.drop_duplicates('id_date',keep='first')
df2['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])
df2.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
grouped_sum = df2.groupby('id')['day_sum']
rolling_sum = grouped_sum.rolling('28D',closed='left').sum().reset_index()
rolling_sum['id_date'] = rolling_sum['id'].astype('str') + '_' + rolling_sum['DATE'].astype('str')
df['28_sum'] = df['id_date'].map(rolling_sum.set_index('id_date')['day_sum'])
grouped_count = df2.groupby('id')['day_count']
rolling_count = grouped_count.rolling('28D',closed='left').sum().reset_index()
rolling_count['id_date'] = rolling_count['id'].astype('str') + '_' + rolling_count['DATE'].astype('str')
df['28_count'] = df['id_date'].map(rolling_count.set_index('id_date')['day_count'])
df['28_mean'] = df['28_sum'] / df['28_count']
```

The code is fast but cumbersome. I welcome any ideas as to how to avoid the creation of the df2 secondary dataframe and the dubious id_date method.

Comment: `id_date` can be avoided, but I have not yet figured out a way to avoid the second dataframe due to the duplicate dates. see my answer for more detailed code suggestion based off of your code